# In IOS MapView, is there an annotation title call back function or a way to set a target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am displaying a custom MKAnnotationView that when clicked displays a title. I know that I can use:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view;
```

To detect the click on the annotation view. Once the user clicks on this AnnotationView a title pops up for the annotation. What I want to do is go to a new controller when the title is clicked. So my question is: Is there a way to detect a click on the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom MKAnnotationView simply override `setSelected:animated:` to show a custom view instead of the built-in callout. What's in that view, and what happens when the user taps within it, is now up to you.