# MKPinAnnotationView with tappable callout

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am trying to create a pin annotation with callout that is clickable as whole part. I have written it like this, but it doesn't as expected - you need to tap on the button for `mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!)` to be called

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: JJMapAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
  if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
    return nil
  }

  var annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier";
  var pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)

  var rightButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
  pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

  pinView.animatesDrop = true;
  pinView.canShowCallout = true;

  return pinView
}
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

I think it should be possible, because that is the behavior I am observing with Apple maps. You can click wherever on their annotation's callout to be taken to detail view.

Also - when I click anywhere besides the button on callout it behaves as a button - it highlights for the time of tap. But the calloutAccessoryControlTapped won't be called and I didn't find any API function that could be called for that event.

I tried with the approach of adding some UIGestureRecognizers, but that doesn't really work considering the callout view is created in flight and is not an annotation view, so there is really no place where to hook it.

Edit: JJMapAnnotation is a subclass of MKPointAnnotation

Comment: It's a delegate method. Prove that your map view has a delegate that implements this method.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you say you can't use a UIGestureRecognizer...

Comment: @matt delegate method is called, but only when you tap on accessory on the callout, not on the callout itself.

Comment: So the problem is just the button? Give it a target-action handler, then.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I am not sure if that is possible.. Where would you add the gesture recognizer to? If I add it to PinAnnotationView, then it will get called on when I tap pin. I would need to get a handle on CalloutView itself to be able to use gesture recognizers

Comment: @matt no, it is not a problem with button, button works, I want the action to be called on tapping whole calloutView, not calloutView's accessory (which, means the button in this case)

Comment: Ok, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26417306/341994

Comment: Intriguing.. But how can you show that custom view considering the annotation view does not know the MKMapView it sits in? Where do you add the view to? Just UIPopover added to AnnotationView will be sufficient? Will it be aware of screen boundaries? I will probably check it, but that sounds perfect.

Comment: You could add the gesture to pinView

Comment: Then it would react on tapping the pin itself, not the calloutView.