# Customize an CallOutView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I've added a title and subtitle to a `CallOut` view, however i've come to the conclusion, that it is rather limited in its ability to add and customize subViews. How can i using swift create a callOutView like below? where there is a bottom button with a different color and a image, title and subtitle?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

New in iOS 9 you can add your own `detailCalloutAccessoryView` which can be anything at all.

Comment: yea but you cant add a view to fille the calloutView there is a margin?

Comment: No, if you want to take over the whole callout you will have to override `setSelected:` and not show the callout when the user selects the annotation (show your own view instead).

Comment: Right, and see my (much shorter) answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26417306/341994